# TikZ: centering nodes and paths relative to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, positioning

I'm trying to draw a textbox over an image like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50cm,paperheight=70cm,margin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{foreground}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1, xscale=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    % IMAGE
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=3.0]{example-image-c}};
    % OUTER RECTANGLE
    \path[draw=foreground,fill=background,line width=1.600pt]
      (232,465) rectangle (512,586);
    % INNER RECTANGLE
    \path[draw=foreground,fill=background,line width=0.800pt]
      (241,476) rectangle (502,576);
    % TITLE
    \path[fill=foreground] (340.3773,522.9204) node[above right] (text3826) {TITLE};
    % SUBTITLE
    \path[fill=foreground] (331.4183,546.7606) node[above right] (text3830) {SUBTITLE};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How do I:

1. Horizontally center OUTER RECTANGE within IMAGE.
2. Center INNER RECTANGLE within OUTER RECTANGLE.
3. Center TITLE and SUBTITLE within INNER RECTANGLE as shown.

I don't want to use precise coordinates like `(241,476)` all over the place. Any alternative ways of drawing this (even without TikZ) would be welcome!

Comment: Please can you make your code compilable and use an image we all have, such as `example-image` or `example-image-c` or whatever?

Comment: @cfr's proposal is better, but if you *really* need to put the boxes at these coordinates, just put them at the center of the coordinates and assign them the necessary `minimum width` and `minimum height`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd name the node with the image and then place the other things relative to that, using `positioning` and `fit`. The picture then consists of three nodes: the picture, the box with text and a box with the thick outer line.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{2C414C}
\definecolor{foreground}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text=foreground, draw=foreground, fill=background, font=\sffamily\LARGE]
  \node (n) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \node (o) [draw, fill, double distance=2.5ex, double=background, line width=.8pt, inner ysep=20pt, inner xsep=50pt, anchor=south, above=5ex of n.south, align=center] {TITLE\\SUBTITLE};
  \node [draw, line width=1.6pt, fit=(o), inner sep=1.25ex] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes in layers]

Comment: Thanks, `positioning` and `fit` are exactly what is needed here!